# How to access the Node server hosted in my laptop from a device in another network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, response

I have written this test.js

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {  
// Send the HTTP header   
// HTTP Status: 200 : OK  
// Content Type: text/plain  
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});  
// Send the response body as "Hello World"  
response.end('Hello World\n');  
}).listen(8080,'192.168.1.5');  
// Console will print the message  
console.log('Server running at http://192.168.1.5:8080/');
```

I runned the command node test.js

```
C:\Users\ShalomAlexander\Documents>node test.js
Server running at http://192.168.1.5:8080/
```

This URL is accessible from my laptop and devices connected to the same wifi network. but I'm not able to access it when I switch from wifi network to mobile network on my smartphone.

so how can I make it work on other devices in different networks?

Comment: Well, you simply need to host it on a public server, not on your localhost. (When I say "simply"...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either...

1. host your app on a public server (e.g. a cloud provider) or
2. make your machine publicly available

Second option requires you to do a port opening & proper forwarding from your router to your machine. Also, you probably want some dynamic DNS entry for your IP, because in general you're not having a fixed IP. Just some hints for this - I don't know what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your NodeJs application on a server(eg: heroku). Then you can access it with the hosted URL.

Please check the documentation on deploying your NodeJs application in Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs